# Is it possible to create a hosted mac OSX agent on Visual Studio Team Services build definition?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

On visualstudio.com, I have configured a build running on a hosted agent for my cross platform app.

How can I add an OSX agent?

I've read this: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/actions/agents/v2-osx, but it seems to refer to a "private agent", which isn't hosted to my understanding.

Can I somehow add a hosted OSX build agent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no hosted OSX agent. You'll have to configure your own.

Comment: Thank Daniel. Do you have a reference to the docs that state this?

Comment: @syonip Based on [Hosted agent article](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/agents/hosted), there are just Hosted, Hosted VS2017 and Hosted Linux Preview.

Comment: Cloud hosted macOS/OS X agents were [added in November 2017](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/11/16/cloud-hosted-mac-agents-for-ci-cd-pipelines/)